# ASP.NET Routing in rest service not working in IIS

Tags: rest, routes, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, asp.net-routing

I created a simple rest service with routing enabled. The routing is properly working when i run it locally i.e using asp.net development server. But when I deploy the application in IIS (IIS 7.5) then it and try to access the method in the service i get the error **HTTP 404.0 Not found**. Here is my code :

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class HelloWorldService
{

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date()
    {
        return System.DateTime.Now;
    }

}
```

Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
    }
    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {           
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("ServiceData", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(HelloWorldService)));
    }
```

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I also Enabled HTTP Redirection Feature under

**Windows Features -> Internet Information Services -> Word Wide Web services -> Common HTTP Features**

I also tried Adding handlers like

```
<handlers>
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, 
       Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</handlers>
```

Also i have tried all the other solutions that were suggested on the web but nothing works. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your RegisterRoutes(). It should be:

```
 private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        // Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("HelloWorldService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(HelloWorldService)));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If something was wrong with that i think i should not even work on localhost. Anyways i tried this but it is still not working.

Comment: may I know what template are you using? I recommend use WCF REST Service Template 40(CS). You don't need to configure anything except your RegisterRoute(). Maybe some of your configuration caused that error. See the image I added on my answer.

Comment: I always use 'ASP.NET Empty web allpication'. and i dont even have .svc file in my solution cause i have read somewhere there is no need of it and rest service can be hosted just like normal asp.net website.

Comment: There is available REST Template to be used with less configuration. Try WCF REST Service Template 40(CS). To get it click your visual studio Tools menu then select Extension Manager then click Online Tab, search "REST" then install WCF REST Service Template 40(CS). Then create new vs project and select WCF REST Service application template.

Comment: I still got the error. Configuration is same in both of the projects. The problem is i guess is some setting in the IIS which i missed or it needs to be done but i don't know about it.

Comment: what version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I said in the post. I am using IIS 7.5

Comment: sorry didn't notice that. May I know what version of asp.net you have registered in your IIS (using aspnet_regiis.exe -i command)? What Application Pool does your application is using?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.0.30319. App pool - Integrated managed pipeline and not classic

Comment: You should install asp.net 4.0 in your IIS and use that as your Application Pool. To insall asp.net locate your .NET Farmework 4.0 (usually C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 for 64 Bit). Click Start (Your Windows Start button) and on search bar enter C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
this will install the IIS. Edit your app and use ASP.NET v4.0 as Application Pool

Comment: Dude that is what's installed.

Comment: I used the command that you posted and i got it working. Thanks alot mate...cheers...

Comment: Glad to hear that! After our long discussion now it's working. :)

Comment: Well by default Windows OS doesn't configure the IIS just to be ready to use. There are configurations that we need to do by ourselves. If you enable IIS in your machine you still need to configure something esp. if you are about to deploy web applications locally. One of the configs is installing the ASP.NET in your IIS. There are also cases that your IIS do not have MIME types on the list and you need to manually add it. For example Silverlight app, Fonts, etc.